# React Component rendered from Value: State not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, setstate

I am building an Account Setup Page where Users have to select a Role and get different Setup Steps. I tried to create two different Arrays containing the Step Components for each Role to ease adding new components into the process.
Unfortunately, the States for both creative and company are not updating. For the role state, it works. E.g. when I try to log the value of creative.firstName in a useEffect hook, it only gives me one letter. The state in the Creative First Name component is not updating at all.

This is my Setup Page where I update the steps array when the role value changes:

```
import { NextPage } from "next";
import React, { ReactNode, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Company, Creative } from "../../../customTypes";
import CompanyName from "../../components/welcome/company/CompanyName";
import FirstName from "../../components/welcome/creative/FirstName";
import UserRole from "../../components/welcome/UserRole";

const Welcome: NextPage = () => {
  const [role, setRole] = useState<"creative" | "company" | null>(null);

  const [creative, setCreative] = useState<Creative>({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    artistName: "",
    handle: "",
  });

  const [company, setCompany] = useState<Company>({
    name: "",
    handle: "",
  });

  type Step = {
    caption?: string;
    component: ReactNode;
    validate: () => boolean;
  };

  const STEPS: Step[] = [
    {
      caption: "Select your role",
      component: <UserRole role={role} setRole={setRole} />,
      validate: () => {
        if (role === null) return false;
        return true;
      },
    },
  ];

  const CREATIVE_STEPS: Step[] = [
    {
      component: <FirstName creative={creative} setCreative={setCreative} />,
      validate: () => {
        if (creative.firstName === "") return false;
        return true;
      },
    },
  ];

  const COMPANY_STEPS: Step[] = [
    {
      component: <CompanyName company={company} setCompany={setCompany} />,
      validate: () => {
        if (company.name === "") return false;
        return true;
      },
    },
  ];

  const [step, setStep] = useState<number>(0);
  const [steps, setSteps] = useState<Step[]>(STEPS);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (role === "creative") {
      setSteps([...STEPS, ...CREATIVE_STEPS]);
    }
    if (role === "company") {
      setSteps([...STEPS, ...COMPANY_STEPS]);
    }
  }, [role]);

  return (
    <div className="mx-auto flex h-screen max-w-3xl flex-col justify-center px-4 py-12">
      <h1 className="mb-12 text-2xl font-bold">{steps[step]?.caption}</h1>
      <div className="flex flex-col">{steps[step]?.component}</div>
      <div className="mt-4 flex items-center justify-end gap-2">
        {step > 0 && (
          <button
            onClick={() => step > 0 && setStep(step - 1)}
            className="rounded-md border py-2 px-6 text-sm text-text hover:border-dark hover:text-dark dark:border-light/50 dark:text-light/50 dark:hover:border-light dark:hover:text-light"
          >
            Back
          </button>
        )}
        <button
          onClick={() =>
            step < steps.length - 1 &&
            steps &&
            steps[step]?.validate() &&
            setStep(step + 1)
          }
          className={`rounded-md border border-primary bg-primary py-2 px-6 text-sm text-light ${
            steps && steps[step]?.validate() ? "opacity-100" : "opacity-50"
          }`}
        >
          Next
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="fixed top-0 left-0 right-0 h-2 bg-gray-200">
        <div
          className={`absolute left-0 top-0 bottom-0 z-10 h-full bg-primary duration-300 ease-[cubic-bezier(0.48,0.21,0.7,1.16)] ${
            step === steps.length ? "rounded-none" : "rounded-r-md"
          }`}
          style={{
            width: step > 0 ? (step / steps.length) * 100 + "%" : "15%",
          }}
        ></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Welcome;
```

This is my component the change the first name:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Creative } from "../../../../customTypes";

interface Props {
  creative: Creative;
  setCreative: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Creative>>;
}

const FirstName: React.FC<Props> = ({ creative, setCreative }) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col">
      <label className="font-semibold">First Name</label>
      <p className="mt-2 text-xs text-text dark:text-light/60">
        Your First Name will not be published.
      </p>
      <input
        type="text"
        className="mt-2 rounded-md border bg-transparent py-2 px-4 text-sm"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setCreative((prev: Creative) => ({
            ...prev,
            firstName: e.target.value,
          }));
        }}
        value={creative.firstName}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default FirstName;
```

This is my Creative type:

```
export type Creative = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  artistName: string;
  handle: string;
};
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you reproduce your project by forking this [CodeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-xlpsg)? It's a React project since your problem seems to be a state issue.

Comment: Sorry for the silence. I think the issue was produced because I rendered the Components later from the CREATIVE_STEPS or COMPANY_STEPS array. Therefore, the state wasn't updated correctly. When triggering a re-render of the component (e.g. through changing a random line of code), the state has been updated.

I decided to remove this kind of array-rendering and switched to the classis { condition && <Component /> } approach.